# OffChain code for inline datum

Tags: plutus, offchain, inline-datum

I am trying to create a OffChain code for submitting inline datums.

```
gTest :: forall w s. GrabParams -> PlutusContract.Contract w s DataText.Text ()
gTest GrabParams{..} = do
    PlutusContract.logInfo @P.String $ TextPrintf.printf "------------------------------------------------------"
    PlutusContract.logInfo @P.String $ TextPrintf.printf "------------------- GTest endpoint -------------------"
    PlutusContract.logInfo @P.String $ TextPrintf.printf "------------------------------------------------------"
    maybeutxo <- findUtxoInValidator grabRedeem
    PlutusContract.logInfo @P.String $ TextPrintf.printf "datum utxos %s" (P.show maybeutxo)
    case maybeutxo of
        Nothing -> PlutusContract.logInfo @P.String $ TextPrintf.printf "Wrong guess %d" grabRedeem
        Just (oref, o) -> do
            PlutusContract.logInfo @P.String $ TextPrintf.printf "Redeem utxos %s" (P.show oref)
            let 
                d = OnChain.Dat
                    { 
                          ddata = grabRedeem
                        , dtype = OnChain.Test
                    }
                r = OnChain.Redeem 
                    {
                        OnChain.redeem = grabRedeem
                    }
                q = 4000000
                lookups = Constraints.unspentOutputs (Map.singleton oref o) P.<>
                          Constraints.plutusV2OtherScript OnChain.validator
                tx = (Constraints.mustPayToOtherScriptWithDatumInTx OnChain.validatorHash (ScriptsLedger.Datum $ PlutusTx.toBuiltinData d) (lovelaceValueOf q)) <>
                     (Constraints.mustIncludeDatumInTx  (ScriptsLedger.Datum $ PlutusTx.toBuiltinData d)) <>
                     (Constraints.mustSpendScriptOutput oref $ ScriptsLedger.Redeemer $ PlutusTx.toBuiltinData r) 
            PlutusContract.logInfo @P.String $ TextPrintf.printf "[GTEST TX] %s" (P.show tx)            
            submittedTx <- PlutusContract.submitTxConstraintsWith @OnChain.Simple lookups tx
            Monad.void $ PlutusContract.awaitTxConfirmed $ LedgerTx.getCardanoTxId submittedTx
            PlutusContract.logInfo @P.String $ "collected gifts"
```

I even tried the Constraints.mustPayToOtherScriptWithInlineDatumInTx and still doesn't include the inline datum.

Comment: What plutus-apps tag/branch are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`Constraint.mustPayToOtherScriptWithInlineDatumInTx` doesn't exist on `main` branch. Use `Constraint.mustPayToOtherScriptWithInlineDatum` without other datum-related constraints to avoid conflict.